# Android Trouble fetching the value from EditText in a Fragment which is using a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a simple fragment with a ViewPager. In the same fragment, I have a EditText to capture the text entered by user.

I have a Adapter which extends PagerAdapter and I have got OnClick event for a button in the instantiateItem method as shown below. When I try to get the reference for this EditText both inside the OnClick method or outside, I don't see the value being fetched. Strangely, I see that sometimes, it displays the result and sometimes it doesn't

here is my Adapter class..

```
public class ProposalSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> imageResourcess = new ArrayList<>();
private String[] imageResources = {"James", "Mick"};

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView notesEntered;
EditText notes = null;
View itemView;
String notedEnteredByUser;

public ProposalSwipeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProposalDetailModel> list) {
    this.context = context;
    //this.imageResourcess = list;
    for (ProposalDetailModel objectProposal : list
            ) {
        //ProposalDetailModel objectProposal1 = new ProposalDetailModel();
        //objectProposal1.setIntroWhatDoWeDo(objectProposal.getIntroWhoAreWe());
        //objectProposal1.setDateOfBusiness(objectProposal.getDateOfBusiness());
        this.imageResourcess.add("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                       INTRODUCTION \n\n\n\n\nABOUT THE COMPANY:" + objectProposal.getIntroWhoAreWe() +
                "\n\nWHAT DO WE DO:" + objectProposal.getIntroWhatDoWeDo() +
                "\n\nTOTAL EMPLOYEES:" +
                "\n\nOFFICIAL LOCATION:" +
                "\n\nFOUNDING YEAR:");


        this.imageResourcess.add("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                       PRODUCT/SERVICE \n\n\n\nSERVICE/PRODUCT OFFERED:" + objectProposal.getIntroWhoAreWe() +
                "\n\nTYPE OF CUSTOMERS:" + objectProposal.getAddres() +
                "\n\nWHY WILL THEY BUY IT:" +
                "\n\nPRODUCT PRICE:" +
                "\n\nCOMPETITORS:" +
                "\n\nSERVICE DELIVERY:");

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    int index = imageResourcess.indexOf(object);
    if (index == -1)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    else
        return index;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageResourcess.size();
    //return imageResources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.proposal_swipe, null);
    Button proposalNotesBtn;

    TextView tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proposalText);
    tv.setText(imageResourcess.get(position).toString());
    container.addView(itemView);
    proposalNotesBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proposalNotesBtn);


    proposalNotesBtn.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            notesEntered = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.enteredNotes);
            notes = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesText);
            notedEnteredByUser = notes.getText().toString();
            notesEntered.setText(notedEnteredByUser);
            Log.i("NOTES ENTERED", notedEnteredByUser);
        }
    });
    if(itemView != null) {
        ((ViewGroup)itemView.getParent()).removeView(itemView);
    }
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    //container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

and the fragment here..

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/proposalText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/notesText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/proposalText"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/proposalNotesBtn"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Save Notes" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/enteredNotes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_below="@id/proposalNotesBtn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Please guide me if I am missing any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the text by using TextWatcher method. Also, I implemented FragmentPagerAdapter instead of PagerAdapter which was very useful.

```
notes = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesText);
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        notedEnteredByUser = charSequence.toString();
        Log.i("TEXTWATCHER", notedEnteredByUser);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};
notes.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is each item on button click you are doing this

```
notes = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesText);
```

It should done once somewhere top along with

```
proposalNotesBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proposalNotesBtn);
```

When initialize the new instance of  `EditText` is created, so that it will retunr empty.

Comment: If you see my latest comment, I have moved this outside the setOnClickListener method but I am setting the text inside the onclicklistener. The reference to the text I am setting this value is outside the onclicklistener, so I am not sure why is it still displaying it in the next slide

Comment: You can set text to TextView before the button click, you may have change the logic you used here. Since on button click don't go for initializing your view components.

Comment: Ok. I moved the setText just above the button click event and I don't see any change to the result.